# How to create freeze authority on already minted token

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, rust, freeze-token-account, freeze

I am trying to create a freeze authority and assign to an escrow account using smart contract on already minted token by me ("Update Authority: //My Pubkey//") ("Mint Authority"://Metaplex derived Mint pubkey//)
NFT: https://solscan.io/token/FCd4keALgeGDUU7ftcz79sK3E31NYr4ZE1XkFqBcYjY5?cluster=devnet#metadata

My code goes this:

```
        token::set_authority(ctx.accounts.into_set_authority_context(), spl_token::instruction::AuthorityType::FreezeAccount, 
    Some(ctx.accounts.escrow_account.key()))?;

    fn into_set_authority_context(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, SetAuthority<'info>> {
    let cpi_accounts = SetAuthority {
        account_or_mint: self.mint.to_account_info().clone(),
        current_authority: self.initializer.clone(),
    };
    CpiContext::new(self.token_program.clone(), cpi_accounts)
}
```

but i get following error:

> 'Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority',
> 'Program log: Error: owner does not match',
> mostly because there is no current freeze authority.

Help is highly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: `self.initializer` is likely not `AccountInfo<'_>`, does changing it to `self.initializer.to_account_info()` have an effect? otherwise if would help to include some of the client code that is creating the account and setting the freeze account

Comment: @m_callens, thanks for the response! :)
this syntax is working for changing other kinds of Authority, getting this error in freezing only, mostly because there is no current authority for freeze.